# How to handle "Select All" option in drop-down for multiple selection value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, msbi

I am facing an issue in SSRS. There is a drop-down parameter of multiple select value. By default it gives "(Select All)" option. If user choose this 'Select All' value then I want to show a label "--All--" on a text box . But I am not able catch this (Select All) option in the expression of text box. Generally we can handle other values in this way..
=Parameters!BranchName.Label(n)

Kindly suggest me any idea to catch this "Select All" option in expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a dataset which same with your dropdown binding value, but select count(*).
2. And use below expression.

> =IIF(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Count = 4 , "Selected All","Not All")

Comment: Thanks Marco Bong .. :). I got the required output.

Answer (score 0):

set default values for the required parameters.
parameter properties > default values > Get values from a query